How to make infinite animation of vertical lines moving along horizontal lines
How to make an infinite animation of vertical lines moving along horizontal lines using only CSS and HTML?

So far I have only got this option, but the distance between the lines does not decrease as the lines from the left approach the center and from the right approach the center, there is no effect of moving away into the depth


.animation-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.animation-container.left {
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 2px, transparent 2px);
  background-size: 58px 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 0% 100%);
  animation: moveLeftToCenter 20s linear infinite;
}

.animation-container.right {
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 2px, transparent 2px);
  background-size: 58px 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 30%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 70%);
  animation: moveRightToCenter 20s linear infinite;
}
<div className='animation-container left w-1/2' />
<div className='animation-container right w-1/2' />



Maybe someone knows how to do this?


You can figure out how it's implemented here. https://codepen.io/konstantindenerz/pen/WNgEqbG

Look into CSS 3d transformations and learn about keyframes.
